# Conditional parsing of array objects of JSON files with PowerShell

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

I use PowerShell to parse the JSON file with array objects. My JSON file is like:

#### File *Test.json*

```
{
    "My Test Plan A": {
        "VariableA":"A",
        "VariableB":"B",
        "VariableC":"C",
        "VariableD":"D"
      },
    "My Test Plan B": {
        "VariableA":"E",
        "VariableB":"F",
        "VariableC":"G",
        "VariableD":"H"
    }
}
```

As you can see, there are two objects, `My Test Plan A` and `My Test Plan B` in my JSON file. And each object has the same variable name, but their values are different.

When the name of the array object is given, how can I get the variables of the corresponding array, so that I can get all the variables in the array for the next code to use?

After obtaining the corresponding array variable, how can the expression to obtain it in the following code be, like `$(VariableA)`?

**Note**:

The JSON file is written by myself. If it is not suitable, please modify it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to use individual variables, use the [intrinsic `.psobject` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#psobject) to obtain the properties of the target object, and set variables based on them using [`Set-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable):

```
# Specify the name of the target property
$name = 'My Test Plan B'

Get-Content -Raw file.json | 
  ConvertFrom-Json |
  ForEach-Object { 
    foreach ($p in $_.$name.psobject.Properties) { 
      Set-Variable $p.Name $p.Value
    }
  }
```

However, note that you could just use the target object *as a whole* and *access its properties* in lieu of defining multiple variables:

```
# Specify the name of the target property
$name = 'My Test Plan B'

$object = (Get-Content -Raw file.json | ConvertFrom-Json).$name

# Now you can use $object.VariableA, ...
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Joy; my pleasure.